# How to write Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Tags: math-mode

What is the best way to write a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)? Isn't there any standard command in LaTeX? For example, a command `\binom` is for binomial coefficients.

In the wikipedia article on Stirling number of the second kind, they used `\atop` command. But people say `\atop` is [not](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) recommended.

Comment: Even putting any technical reasons aside, `\atop` is a bad choice as it left-aligns the "numerator" and "denominator", rather than centring them.

Comment: A simple approach is `{n \brace k}`, but I guess it's not "real LaTeX" style.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Note from the future: I just tested and `atop` centers the numerator and denominator, unless you're doing something very wrong. ■ Related question: [math mode - Multiset notation in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/multiset-notation-in-latex/5825#5825), [amsmath - On \atop again: how to obtain the same result without warning - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119096/on-atop-again-how-to-obtain-the-same-result-without-warning)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following is taken from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and uses `\genfrac` - a generic fraction function:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareRobustCommand{\stirling}{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}}
\begin{document}
% Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind
In mathematics, particularly in combinatorics, a Stirling number of the second kind 
is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$~objects into $k$~non-empty subsets and 
is denoted by~$S(n,k)$ or~$\stirling{a}{b}$. Stirling numbers of the second kind occur 
in the field of mathematics called combinatorics and the study of partitions.
\end{document}
```

How does this work? `\genfrac` takes five arguments to create a structure (from the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf); section **4.11.3 The `\genfrac` command**, p 14):

> The last two correspond to `\frac`’s numerator and denominator; the
>   first two are optional delimiters [...]; the third is a line thickness
>   override [0 implies an invisible rule]; and the fourth argument is a
>   mathstyle override: integer values 0-3 select respectively
>   `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and
>   `\scriptscriptstyle`. If the third argument is left empty, the line
>   thickness defaults to ‘normal’.

So `\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}` creates a fraction with an invisible horizontal rule (third argument is `0pt`), left and right delimiter given by `\{` and `\}`, respectively and no specific math style (an empty `{}` fourth argument). `\stirling` doesn't include a fifth and sixth argument for `\genfrac` (numerator and denominator), because this is implicitly supplied by the user as the two "arguments" to `\stirling`.

In a similar manner (perhaps for reference), `amsmath` defines

```
\newcommand{\frac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{}{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\binom}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

using `\genfrac`.

Comment: How would you declare a Stirling number of the first kind using `\genfrac`?

Comment: @Jim: [egreg provides `\stirlingI`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462052/5764) that uses `\genfrac`.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a plain pdfTeX solution, just to illustrate what type of typesetting Knuth used
for such numbers (he wrote a few papers on this topic)

```
% ========= Fonts
\font\sc=cmcsc10
% ========== Heading macros
\magnification =\magstep 1
\overfullrule =0pt
%

\noindent 1. {\sc Stirling numbers} ---
Stirling cycle numbers ${ n\brack m}$ are defined  by
$$ \ln^m(1+z) = m! \sum_n (-1)^{n+m} { n\brack m} {z^n\over n!}
  \ .\leqno(1a) $$
The numbers $(-1)^{n+m}{n\brack m}$ are also called Stirling numbers of the first kind.
Stirling subset numbers ${n\brace m}$, also called Stirling numbers
of the second kind, are defined by
$$ \left( e^z-1\right)^m = m! \sum_n {n\brace m} {z^n\over n!}
  \ ,\leqno(1b) $$
and 2-associated Stirling subset numbers ${n\brace m}_{\ge 2}$ are
defined by 

$$ \left( e^z-1-z\right)^m = m!\sum_n {n\brace m}_{\!\ge 2} {z^n\over n!}
  \ .\leqno(1c) $$

\bye
```

[image]

You can have a look at more examples at [Knuth Papers](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/preprints.html#ref)

Comment: Wow. I am tempted to learn `plain` typesetting.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Not really necessary. If you place the code between `\begin{document}...\end{document}` it will work with LaTeX as well; `amsmath` will complain about the `\over` though, if you using it. They can easily be converted to amsmath styles.

Comment: Take a look specially at Knuth's P137 from the link above, it's called "Two notes on notation" and it's precisely about the Stirling numbers.

Answer (score 9):

There is a `Bmatrix` environment in `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{Bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{Bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the formula should be sum with upper limit $k$.

Comment: Done @dexteritas, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It makes sense to define all at once:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\genstirlingI}[3]{%
  \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\genstirlingII}[3]{%
  \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\stirlingI}[2]{\genstirlingI{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\dstirlingI}[2]{\genstirlingI{0}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tstirlingI}[2]{\genstirlingI{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\stirlingII}[2]{\genstirlingII{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\dstirlingII}[2]{\genstirlingII{0}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tstirlingII}[2]{\genstirlingII{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

The Stirling symbol of the first kind $\stirlingI{n}{k}$
or of the second kind $\stirlingII{n}{k}$
\[
\stirlingI{n}{k} \ne \stirlingII{n}{k}
\]
We can also choose the size
\[
\frac{\stirlingI{n}{k}+\stirlingII{n}{k}}{3}\quad
\frac{\dstirlingI{n}{k}+\dstirlingII{n}{k}}{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]