# Vertical aligning for simple numbers

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

I need to typset a series of fractions with no line inside some paragraphs of text (they were used as proportional symbols). It is very simple, actually:

$^2_1$, $^4_2$,$^8_4$

But when it comes to `$^{12}_{6}$`, the two numbers are not aligned vertically.

If I use a fraction `$\frac{12}{6}$` the alignment is good, but the horizontal line shouldn't be there.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,
A

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

I need this $^{12}_{6}$ aligned vertically like this $\frac{12}{6}$.

\end{document}
```

Following all answers, I have to say all of them work fine, but they do not produce a result which is identical to `$^{12}_{6}$`. The problem arises when you have more than one instance in the same context, and I believe the  `$^{12}_{6}$` spacing is the optimal one. See the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\myfrac}%  % macro with LaTeX-style syntax
    [2]{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\scriptstyle #1 \\[-1.2ex]\scriptstyle #2\end{array}}
\begin{document}

\noindent Myfrac plus smash as by the example by Harish and Harold compared with optimal vertical spacing: $^{1}_{2}$, \smash{$\myfrac{22}{6}$}, $^{4}_{2}$, $^{2}_{1}$; can you see the difference? My proofreader will kill me, my proofreader will kill me, my proofreader will kill me :-).


\end{document}
```

[image: The 2 in the second fraction is positioned lower]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question includes: "If I use a fraction $\frac{12}{6}$ the alignment is good, but the horizontal line shouldn't be there." This is the reason why there are answers which emulates exactly fraction but without line. After edit of the question, we can read:"the answers do not produce a result which is identical to $^{12}_{6}$". Of course, this was not in the first placing. But we can do this if we know, what exacly does the `^` and `_`. We can emulate this work by `\halign`.

```
% \cei^{exp}_{ind} = Center Exponent and Index
\def\cei^#1_#2{\lower\fontdimen17\textfont2\vbox{%
   \baselineskip=\fontdimen17\textfont2 \advance\baselineskip by\fontdimen14\textfont2
   \halign{\hfil$\scriptstyle##$\hfil\cr#1\cr#2\cr}%
}}
```

You can add this code before `\begin{document}` (if you are using LaTeX) and you can type in your document:

```
... $^{1}_{2}$, $\cei^{22}_{6}$, $^{4}_{2}$, $^{2}_{1}$; ...
```

[image: cei]

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far.

Answer (score 8):

In a similar way to how one can define [Sterling numbers of the second kind](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86056/5764), [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\genfrac` can be used to set a fraction that has no horizontal line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\psymbol}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tpsymbol}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\dpsymbol}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
It's easy to see that $\psymbol{a}{b}$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ is always $\tpsymbol{2}{1}$ and $\tfrac{2}{1}$ and sometimes
$\psymbol{12}{6}$ and $\frac{12}{6}$. Also,
\[
  f(x,y) = \psymbol{36}{18}\ \frac{36}{18} \quad \text{while} \quad g(x) = \tpsymbol{108}{54}\ \tfrac{108}{54}.
\]
Maybe one can also define $\begin{smallmatrix}16 \\ 8\end{smallmatrix}$ and $\frac{16}{8}$.
\end{document}
```

`amsmath` also offers `smallmatrix` that can be used to set a similar vertically stacked structure.

Comment: $\begin{smallmatrix}16 \\ 8\end{smallmatrix}$ does the right trick, thank you!

Comment: $\begin{smallmatrix}16 \\ 8\end{smallmatrix}$ does the trick, but it creates too much space around the fraction.

Answer (score 8):

There is a TeX math-mode primitive called `\atop` that does exactly what you need. However, it uses so-called infix notation and is not widely used in LaTeX. Fortunately, it's not difficult to create a LaTeX-style macro called, say, `\myatop` that mimics the syntax of the LaTeX macro `\frac`. In fact, the construction of the `\myatop` macro in the example below is exactly analogous to to the construction of the LaTeX macro `\frac`.

The following code shows the results of this using this macro, as well as the plain-TeX `\atop` macro and the `\frac` macro. (Thanks to the great suggestion by @wipet, the upper number using `\atop` is now at the same height as it would be when using `\frac` when used in inline math mode.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myatop}[2]{%  % a macro with LaTeX-style syntax
    \fontdimen10\textfont2=\fontdimen9\textfont2% using wipet's suggestion
    {\begingroup#1\endgroup\atop#2}}    
\begin{document}
inline math mode:\quad ${22\atop 6} \quad \myatop{22}{6} \quad \frac{22}{6}$

\bigskip

display math mode: $\displaystyle {22\atop6} \quad \myatop{22}{6} \quad \frac{22}{6} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be a good solution, but the numbers appear too far from each other.

Comment: @user56153 - glad you found my proposed solution good . :-) By the way, the vertical separation generated by `\atop` is identical to that generated by `\genfrac` in the accepted answer.

Comment: See the last example with $\begin{smallmatrix}16 \\ 8\end{smallmatrix}$. It has the right separation space between the numbers, but it's got too much white space before and after the fraction.

Comment: Note: `\atop` generates numerator to higher place in text style than normal fraction by `\over` (your picture is clear). The reason is that `\atop` uses `\fontdimen10\font2` but `\over` uses `\fontdimen9`. See TeXbook p. 444, rule 15b. If you need to correct this, you can type (in plain TeX) `\fontdimen10\textfont2=\fontdimen9\textfont2` but this doesn't work in LaTeX because of silly NFSS. You have to put this in `\everymath` or use trick with negative thickness of the rule: `{22 \above-1pt 6}`.

Comment: @wipet - Many thanks for these very detailed comments and suggestions! I've followed your suggestion to use `\everymath` to effect the reset of \fontdimen10 and posted a new MWE and graph.

Comment: @user56153 - I've modified the code to address your concern that the upper number is set too high when using `\atop`. (wipet's suggestions were perfect.)

Answer (score 5):

Why not use an `array` or `tabular`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myfrac}%  % macro with LaTeX-style syntax
    [2]{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1 \\[-0.75ex]#2\end{array}}
\begin{document}
 $\myfrac{22}{6}$, and $\myfrac{22}{6}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it to be small:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myfrac}%  % macro with LaTeX-style syntax
    [2]{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\scriptstyle #1 \\[-1.2ex]\scriptstyle #2\end{array}}
\begin{document}
 $\myfrac{22}{6}$, and $\myfrac{22}{6}$

 I need this $\myfrac{12}{6}$ aligned vertically like this $\frac{12}{6}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a smaller version:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\myfrac}%  % macro with LaTeX-style syntax
    [2]{\raise.12ex\hbox{$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\scriptstyle #1 \\[-1.35ex]\scriptstyle #2\end{array}$}}
\begin{document}

\noindent Myfrac plus smash as by the example by Harish and Harold compared with optimal vertical spacing: $^{1}_{2}$, \smash{$\myfrac{22}{6}$}, $^{22}_{6}$, $^{2}_{1}$; can you see the difference? My proofreader will kill me, my proofreader will kill me, my proofreader will kill me :-).


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution would be good, but it is too large in height, so that it affects the paragraph height of my text.

Comment: In your smaller version the space between numbers is correct, but if you put this code in a typeblock, you will end up with too much space between two lines of the pargraph. Plus, the numbers are smaller than $^12_&$.

Comment: @user56153 See the update. Is that OK?

Comment: @user56153 If you want to avoid effect to the paragraph height, you can also `\smash{}` it :)

Comment: Harish and Harald, thank you for your suggestions, but see my question edits.

Comment: @user56153 See the update.

Comment: Harish, so the solution was to introduce \raise.12ex. Thank you so much, now my proofreader won't kill me anymore :-).

Comment: We are talking about such -1.35ex as a Pisvejc number. It means number fallen from heavens. See my answer which simulates _exactly_ the `^` and `_`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `subarray` environment of `amsmath`, that also allows left alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pseudofrac}[2]{%
  \begin{subarray}{l}#1\\#2\end{subarray}%
}

\begin{document}

I need this $\pseudofrac{12}{6}$ aligned vertically like this $\frac{12}{6}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `harmony` package creates very tightly spaced, vertically aligned and centered numerals with the `\Takt` command. It is intended for time signatures in musicological writing (*Takt* is German for "measure" or "time").

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rm]{harmony} 
    % rm option uses the roman family instead of the default sans-serif

\begin{document}

\Takt{12}{6}

\Takt{135}{222}

\Takt{3}{1478}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the `harmony` package until I read your answer. Neat!

Answer (score 3):

A solution that relies on the `stackengine` package. I define  a `\varfrac` command in math mode and a `\varfractext`command for textmode. An optional argument  is the vertical spacing between the numerator and denominator (separated by `\\`), that defaults to 8pt.

Depending on the contents of the fraction you may reduce or increase this spacing. Another way of adjusting would be to slighltly increase the value of `\baselinestretch` for the whole document, as vertical spacing defined by LaTeX is really tight. I give an example where I increase the value of `\baselineskip` by 6 %, with the help of the `setspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\myfrac}% % macro with LaTeX-style syntax
    [2]{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\scriptstyle #1 \\[-1.2ex]\scriptstyle #2\end{array}}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\newcommand\varfractext[2][8pt]{\smash{\setstackgap{L}{#1}\scriptsize\Centerstack{#2}}}
\newcommand\varfrac[2][8pt]{\smash{\setstackgap{L}{#1}\ensurestackMath{\everymath{\scriptstyle}\Vectorstack{#2}}}}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\noindent \verb+\Myfrac+ plus \verb+\smash+ as by the example by Harish and Harold compared with optimal vertical spacing: $^{1}_{2}$, \smash{$\myfrac{22}{6}$}, $^{4}_{2}$, $^{2}_{1}$; can you see the difference? My proofreader will kill me, but my proofreader won't kill me anymore with $ \pi \approx\varfrac{22\\7} $ or better (textmode): \varfractext{355\\113}\enspace \varfractext[6pt]{355\\113}, my proofreader won't kill me anymore, my proofreader won't kill me me anymore:-).\bigskip

\noindent With \verb+\setstretch{1.06}+:\\[1ex]
\verb+\Myfrac+ plus \verb+\smash+ as by the example by Harish and Harold compared with optimal vertical spacing: $^{1}_{2}$, \smash{$\myfrac{22}{6}$}, $^{4}_{2}$, $^{2}_{1}$; can you see the difference? My proofreader will kill me, but my proofreader won't kill me anymore with $ \pi \approx\varfrac{22\\7} $ or better (textmode): \varfractext{355\\113}\enspace \varfractext[6pt]{355\\113}, my proofreader won't kill me anymore, my proofreader won't kill me me anymore:-).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Bernard, your answer is really interesting. Now I just have to choose between many very good options.

Comment: @Mico: Not sure your question is for me. I wonder if you mean  `\myfrac` or `\varfrac(text)`. I'm only wrote the latter, and I guess it could work as you ask, using \mathchoice.