# Typeset a fraction without the fraction bar

Tags: fractions

I would like to typeset a fraction without the fraction bar. In the following MWE, I try to do this using `substack` command from the `mathtools` package. But, as you can see in the output, the spacing is not the same as in the original fraction. How can I typeset a fraction without the fraction bar (not necessarily using `mathtools`?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

$\frac{1}{2}$
$\substack{1\\2}$

\end{document}
```

[image: frac]

Comment: See also [Vertical aligning for simple numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199613/5001).

Answer (score 6):

Use `amsmath`'s `\genfrac` command. (This is how `\binom` is defined.)

It takes quite a few arguments: `\genfrac{<left>}{<right>}{<width>}{<style>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}`

- `<left>` is the delimiter to be used on the left. In the case of `\binom` it is `(`
- `<right>` is the delimiter on the right.
- `<width>` is the width of the rule that runs between the numerator and denominator.
- `<style>` is to override defaults and force the fraction to be set in `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle` etc.

So what you want can be accomplished by `\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{2}`.

If you are going to use it a lot, defined a command:

```
\newcommand{\nobarfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}}
```

should do the trick. Call it with `\nobarfrac{1}{2}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86059/119 for a more thorough explanation than the one I wrote.