# Better double parenthesis notation for multiset

Tags: spacing, symbols, parenthesis

In my combinatorics homework I use double parenthesis to represent a multiset. I have referred to all the answers under [Multiset notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/multiset-notation-in-latex) on how to build such a notation.

However, the double parenthesis looks good alone but when put together with a binomial, it looks very inconsistent.

I used the code that come from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5825/91144, which utilizes a `\genfrac` with `left(`/`right)`.

```
\def\multiset#1#2{\ensuremath{\left(\kern-.3em\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\right)\kern-.3em\right)}}
```

Here are four problematic examples

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\multiset#1#2{\ensuremath{\left(\kern-.3em\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\right)\kern-.3em\right)}}

\begin{document}

\verb~$\multiset{5}{k}+\multiset{5}{k-1}+\multiset{5}{k-4}$~ \\
$\multiset{5}{k}+\multiset{5}{k-1}+\multiset{5}{k-4}$

\verb~$\sum_{\substack{i+j=15\\i,j\geq0}}\binom{5}{i}\multiset{3}{j}$~ \\
$\sum_{\substack{i+j=15\\i,j\geq0}}\binom{5}{i}\multiset{3}{j}$

\verb~\[ ab\binom{5}{i}123\multiset{3}{j}cd \]~ \\
\[ ab\binom{5}{i}123\multiset{3}{j}cd \]

\verb~\[ \sum{\multiset{5}{k}\multiset{5}{k}} \]~ \\
\[ \sum_{i=0}^{k}{\multiset{m}{i}\multiset{n}{k-i}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: examples]

1. inconsistent height (inline mode)
2. inconsistent height with `\binom` (inline mode)
3. incorrect spacing, comparing to `\binom` (display mode)
4. inconsistent sizes (display mode)

What I wanted is a notation that looks just similar to `\binom{n}{k}`, i.e. size, shape, spacing, etc, while having two pair of parenthesis around. And I expect it to work both inline and in display mode. Thank you :)

Comment: Source code for the examples?

Comment: But this image of source code! Please make it so, that it can be copied in editor and test it.

Comment: @Zarko: here is it: http://lpaste.net/6732560716236062720

Comment: @ShouYa, ok, why you not copy in your question as minimal working example (without line numbers ...) by this you will make to people here  eaiery to help you.

Comment: The rules for the delimiter size in generalized fractions are different from those for `\left` and `\right`; this is particularly evident in text style. The difference in case 4 is because the `-` has a depth (you'd see the same with `+`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\textmultiset}[2]{\bigl(\!{\binom{#1}{#2}}\!\bigr)}
\newcommand{\displaymultiset}[2]{\left(\!{\binom{#1}{#2}}\!\right)}
\newcommand\multiset[2]{\mathchoice{\displaymultiset{#1}{#2}}
                                {\textmultiset{#1}{#2}}
                                {\textmultiset{#1}{#2}}
                                {\textmultiset{#1}{#2}}}
    \begin{document}
some text $ \multiset{5}{k}+\binom{5}{k-1}+\multiset{5}{k{+}1}$

\bigskip 
some text $\sum_{\substack{i+j=15\\i,j\geq0}}\binom{5}{i}\multiset{3}{j}\multiset{3}{j+1}$

\[ ab\multiset{5}{i+1}123\binom{3}{j+1}cd \]

\[ \sum_{i=0}^{k}{\multiset{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}} \]
    \end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm still wondering if the spacing around the `\multiset` can be better. e.g. `ab␣((5,i+1))␣123` looks wider than `123␣(3,j+1)␣cd`. Should I just add some `\!` around the command or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Instead of `\!` you can use TeX primitive `\kern -<value>`, where you set `<value>` according to your taste. For example, for  `display` version of `\multset` you can try with `\newcommand{\displaymultiset}[2]{\left(\kern-5pt{\binom{#1}{#2}}\!\!\right)}` and see, which distance (left or right) looks nicer to you.

Answer (score 1):

I get somewhat better results by tweaking @Zarko's answer to

```
\newcommand\multiset[2]%
{\mathchoice{\left(\kern-0.5em{\binom{#1}{#2}}\kern-0.5em\right)}
            {\bigl(\kern-0.3em{\binom{#1}{#2}}\kern-0.3em\bigr)}
            {\bigl(\kern-0.3em{\binom{#1}{#2}}\kern-0.3em\bigr)}
            {\bigl(\kern-0.3em{\binom{#1}{#2}}\kern-0.3em\bigr)}}
```

But e.g. `2^{\multiset{2}{3}}` looks ugly (the inner () are a bit too low).