# Multiset symbol

Tags: symbols, amsmath, packages, package-options

Recently in a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794470/generalization-of-multisets) on Math.SE, I have seen for the first time in my life an unknown symbol of double binomial coefficient. It is simply possible to make it with a code of this style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a direct command that produces the double round bracket symbol? I have seen this same answer very old but I not like :-( [Multiset notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/multiset-notation-in-latex).

After almost 10 years is there a command in some package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course construct it with two ( but Unicode has double parenthesis U+2e28 and U+2e29 which looks like

⸨x⸩

which looks like [image] in this browser at least.

But this is in the `Supplemental Punctuation` block so not considered mathematical and indeed Stix Two and Cambria math fonts (at least) don't have that character.

Comment: Always thank you so much for your answers that expand my knowledges.